# WindowsCodecs adding memory footprint of WPF application

Tags: wpf, performance, memory-management

I downloaded Red gate ANTS Memory Profiler and profiled my app. I noticed that my app had a lot of unmanaged memory allocated (160MB). So I ran the profiler again with unmanaged memory profiling enabled. The break down of the unmanaged memory as follows:

WindowsCodecs: 45.19MB
CLR: 43.21MB
Allocated by Managed code: 30.23MB
Allocated before profiling started: 2.047MB
d3d9: 595.5KB
Other modules: 67.27MB

Other modules also contains the red gate memory profiler which accounted for 64.94MB of the 67.27MB.

From reading the Red Gate documentation, loading the CLR is expected to be around 40MB and my managed code allocating 30MB seems reasonable. But I am confused by the WindowsCodecs taking up 45MB! I am assuming that WindowsCodex is related to video codecs or playback. My app does not use Windows Media Player media control nor does it do any media playback of any sort (audio or video).

Anybody run into this? It appears my app could get a 45MB memory footprint reduction if I can figure out what is pulling in this dependency.

Comment: As far as I know, the Windows Codecs are not just for Video, but also for images. Are you displaying jpegs or png's or other still image files?

Comment: I am displaying PNGs and JPEGs yes.

Comment: Well, that would explain it then. If you want to confirm, create a small WPF app without any bitmap images.